Rust error[E0597]: does not live long enough
I am trying to simplify this nodejs-polars code.
I have path_or_buffer: Either<String, Buffer> as a function param.
When trying to match:
let file = match path_or_buffer {
   Either::A(path) => Box::new(std::fs::File::open(path).unwrap()) as Box<dyn MmapBytesReader>,
   Either::B(buffer) => Box::new(Cursor::new(buffer.as_ref())) as Box<dyn MmapBytesReader>
}

I get: error[E0597]: buffer does not live long enough Thx

Try Cursor::new(buffer) so the cursor owns the buffer.

You shouldn't turn things into trait objects when it's not necessary, especially when references are involved. Make a generic function instead: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cf69be29c5e5e688e8e4797b1d11d768

This approach would almost work, except that the Polars team has made a lot of changes in RS-0.4 and now I need to use: .into_reader_with_file_handle(csv())
(https://github.com/Bidek56/nodejs-polars/blob/2c42a1892f7d960e7a53eff6a0e725015fa9818a/src/dataframe.rs#L156) which does not work due to: the trait MmapBytesReader is not implemented for polars::prelude::CsvReader<B>

Could it be that the type coercion does not work as expected and you are required to specify it in your function calls or as a return type for the closures?

When I refactor the function to be:
fn reader_to_df<B: MmapBytesReader>(     csv: impl FnOnce() -> Box<dyn MmapBytesReader>,     options: ReadCsvOptions, ) -> napi::Result<JsDataFrame> {....
I get:
--> src/dataframe.rs:171:28     | 171 |           Either::A(path) => reader_to_df(     |  ____________________________^ 172 | |             || Box::new(std::fs::File::open(path).unwrap()) as Box<dyn MmapBytesReader>, 173 | |             options, 174 | |         ),     | |_________^ cannot infer type for type parameter B declared on the functionreader_to_df
`

My solution turned to be rather simple, Box::new turned out to be the problem.
fn mmap_reader_to_df<'a>(
    csv: impl MmapBytesReader + 'a,
    options: ReadCsvOptions,
) -> napi::Result<JsDataFrame> {...}

then to call it:
pub fn read_csv(
    path_or_buffer: Either<String, Buffer>,
    options: ReadCsvOptions,
) -> napi::Result<JsDataFrame> {
    match path_or_buffer {
        Either::A(path) => mmap_reader_to_df(std::fs::File::open(path).expect("unable to read file"), options),
        Either::B(buffer) => mmap_reader_to_df(Cursor::new(buffer.as_ref()), options),
    }
}


Please include the code directly in your post preferably with additional description of the solution. Link-only answers are frowned upon and liable to be downvoted or deleted.
